# Clout9 (c9.io) IDE ruby on rails error when run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

When running rails server on cloud9, I get:  No application seems to be running here! I tried removing the workspace, cloning it from a repository on github, and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is:

to start the server, do not simply type

```
  rails s
```

but instead

```
 rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```